# Creating account randomly fails (AccountNotFound)

Tags: solana-py

In my Python code I am creating a new account on the devnet using the [solana module](https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/)'s [`create_account` instruction](https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/core/system_program/#solana.system_program.create_account). Simulation of the transaction **sometimes** fails with the "AccountNotFound" error ("Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit."). If I skip the simulation and directly send the raw transaction to the chain the tx simply doesn't appear when I try to search for it on Solana Explorer. I am absolutely sure that the account paying for the creation of the new account has the required balance.

What I find particularly strange is that this behavior is not deterministic, i.e., re-sending the same transaction eventaully succeeds and the account gets successfully created. This issue might perhaps have a common cause with: [spl-token-cli: "Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit" after `solana airdrop 1`](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/spl-token-cli-attempt-to-debit-an-account-but-found-no-record-of-a-prior-credi)

Any information that might help in understanding the root of this issue would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am adding a minimal example that reproduces the error:

```
import base58
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from solana.system_program import create_account, CreateAccountParams

cli = Client(ENDPOINT, commitment=COMMITMENT)

old_keypair = Keypair.from_seed(base58.b58decode(MY_SECRET)[:32])
new_keypair = Keypair()

if cli.get_account_info(old_keypair.public_key)['result']['value']['lamports'] > 1e9:

    tx = Transaction()

    space = 8 + 4 + 4 + 32
    lamports = cli.get_minimum_balance_for_rent_exemption(space)['result']
    ix = create_account(
        CreateAccountParams(
            from_pubkey=old_keypair.public_key,
            new_account_pubkey=new_keypair.public_key,
            lamports=lamports,
            space=space,
            program_id=PROGRAM_ID))

    tx.add(ix)
    tx = Transaction().add(ix)
    response = cli.send_transaction(tx, old_keypair, new_keypair)
```

Comment: did you figure this out? Have been having the same issue with the same set up and scenario

Answer (score 4):

Your problem almost certainly owes itself to the fact that you are funding the payer and simulating the creation of the account at different levels of **commitment**.

Without seeing your code, I'm going to guess that it looks something like this:

```
const payer = Keypair.generate();
const newAccount = Keypair.generate();

// Step 1: fund the payer's account
await requestAirdrop(payer, 1);

// Step 2: create an account
const tx = createCreateAccountTransaction(payer, newAccount);
await connection.sendTransaction(tx);
```

If you don't specify a *preflight commitment level* in `sendTransaction` then it will default to `finalized`. This means that enough time *must* have passed between step 1 and step 2 for the airdrop to `payer` to have achieved finality. This is where your non-determinism is coming from.

Make sure to confirm *and* simulate each step at the same level of commitment.

```
const commitment = 'confirmed';

// Step 1: fund the payer's account and wait for `commitment`
await connection.confirmTransaction(
  await requestAirdrop(payer, 1),
  commitment,
);

// Step 2: create an account and simulate at same commitment
const tx = createCreateAccountTransaction(payer, newAccount);
await connection.sendTransaction(tx, {
  preflightCommitment: commitment,
});
```

Comment: And yes, I realize that your program is in Python and not JavaScript, but you get the idea :)

Comment: Your answer is a good guess at a potential issue without seeing the code. However, in my case I am sure this is not the problem because I am using an existing account with more than sufficient lamports for creating the new rent-exempt account.
That being said, I am really running out of ideas what could actually be the cause. I have managed to find an open issue regarding this on [Solana-py github pages](https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/issues/96), but it is still unsolved.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: step1 is giving an error in typescript. it is not implemented correctly

Comment: Fixed, though the copy-paste readiness of the code was not really the goal of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved by a [reply on GitHub](https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/issues/96#issuecomment-1284735739).

To summarize, in the example I posted there are two signers of the transaction, where the second one is the newly created account (with no prior funds). I was assuming that the first signer is the fee payer, but somehow that is not always the case. To avoid the problem one needs to manually specify the fee payer on the transaction object:
`tx.fee_payer = old_keypair.public_key`.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue till I looked at [Why does "solana account" fail until after airdrop](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2946/why-does-solana-account-fail-until-after-airdrop). I believe you have to send `0.001` SOL (can't be less I think) to the **wallet** to actually store it and so it registers. So that's probably why making tokens on fresh wallets doesn't work. Try sending the `0.001` first

Comment: The `create_account` instruction should take care of funding the new accout

Comment: I meant wallet not account @mcshell sorry